# z-index not working in the service item

Tags: html, css

[image]

When I hover the service item, it does not appear above the other items. I am trying to set the z-index but it's not working. What do I next?

Here is my demo link:
http://sarower.me/projects/

Comment: Where/how are you setting the `z-index`? That should work.

Comment: When I hover the item. The item top of the another item. It not working z-index.

Comment: add `z-index: -1;` to all items.

Comment: @Mamun since this is a question about programming, it's best to include some code with your question. I was asking where in your "code" you are setting the `z-index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
.creb:hover {
  z-index: 100;
}
```

That will set the z-index before the animation begins.

Answer (score 2):

Add the z-index for the parent.

```
.creb.animated.fadeInUp:hover {
    z-index: 10;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you have not added any code, but it's a `z-index` issue so you can see below example and update or make changes to your code, hope this help.

```css
#b1{
 width:32%;
 height:200px;
 background:#111;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 transition:1s ease;
 z-index:-1;
}
#b1:hover{
  transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
  z-index:9;
}
#b2{
 width:32%;
 height:200px;
 background:#ff1;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 transition:1s ease;
 z-index:-1;
}
#b2:hover{
  transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
  z-index:9;
}
#b3{
 width:32%;
 height:200px;
 background:#f11;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 transition:1s ease;
 z-index:-1;
}
#b3:hover{
  transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
  z-index:9;
}
```

```html
<div id="b1"></div>
<div id="b2"></div>
<div id="b3"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this its working for me

`.creb:hover {
    z-index: 9999999999;
}`